# Component keeps looping

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my `componentDidMount()` I am calling `this.props.getPost(soloPost._id);` in which case will use redux. This is working correctly, because if I `console.log` it I get my desired result. But `componentDidMount()` is looping continuously. I have a feeling i'm missing something on the component lifecycle

```
class PostItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showCommentField: false
    };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  onClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showCommentField: !prevState.showCommentField
    }));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { soloPost } = this.props;
    this.props.getPost(soloPost._id);
    console.log(this.props.comments);
  }
  render() {
    const { soloPost, classes } = this.props;

    const postContent = (
      <div>
        <CommentFeed postId={soloPost._id} comments={soloPost.comments} />
        <CommentForm postId={soloPost._id} />
      </div>
    );
    return (
      <div className={classes.section}>
        <GridContainer justify="center">
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={10} md={8}>
            <hr />
            <Card plain profile className={classes.card}>
              <GridContainer>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={2} md={2}>
                  <CardAvatar plain profile>
                    <img src={soloPost.avatar} alt="..." />
                  </CardAvatar>
                </GridItem>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={8} md={8}>
                  <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>{soloPost.name}</h4>
                  <p className={classes.description}>{soloPost.text}</p>
                </GridItem>
              </GridContainer>
            </Card>
          </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
        <GridContainer justify="center">
          <Tooltip
            id="tooltip-tina"
            title="Reply to comment"
            placement="top"
            classes={{ tooltip: classes.tooltip }}
          >
            <Button
              color="primary"
              simple
              className={classes.footerButtons}
              onClick={this.onClick}
            >
              <Reply className={classes.footerIcons} /> Reply
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>
        </GridContainer>
        {this.state.showCommentField ? (
          <GridContainer justify="center">
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={5} md={5} lg={5}>
              {postContent}
            </GridItem>
          </GridContainer>
        ) : (
          <div />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PostItem.defaultProps = {
  showActions: true
};

PostItem.propTypes = {
  soloPost: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  comments: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ comments: state.post.post });

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPost }
)(withStyles(sectionBlogInfoStyle)(PostItem));
```

**EDIT**
I just tried this and it looped as well.

```
     shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { soloPost } = this.props;
    if (nextProps !== this.props) {
      this.props.getPost(soloPost._id);
      return true;
    }
    if (nextState !== this.state) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` method is not the one looping, your component does, re-renders actually. This means that somewhere in your code, you are setting state in the `render` method or somehow, something triggers the state. I can't see it in this component. Is it possible this would be in other components? So, try to narrow down your app.

Comment: I just wonder something, you are saying `componentDidMount` is looping. How do you know that? Do you see looping logs (comments) coming from `componentDidMount`? If so this means your component is unmounting/mounting again and this is very weird.

Comment: @devserkan actually componentDidMount only gets called once the component is mounted, not every re-render. So I don't think a setState on render would cause this. Maybe a higher order component is looping and creating new instances of PostItem? Can you post the code of PostItem's parent?

Comment: @ThiagoLoddi, this is why I asked if OP sees the logs from `componentDidMount` or not :) OP says `componentDidMount` is looping. If so, you are right and my first comment is meaningless in this situation. And looking the code again there isn't any handler (besides onClick) that can update this component's state which is passed to children, then this means you are right and my all comments are totally crap :)